# Deploy spring boot app which calls another service on Kubernetes (EKS)

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, deployment

I have a spring boot app A, which calls another application B.

Now I would like to deploy app A on Kubernetes. I was able to deploy somple spring boot app which isn't calling any other sevice but need guidance on deploying sping boot app A calling another app B

Any help on this would be grateful

Thanks

Comment: What do you have so far?  What particular challenges are you running into?

Answer (score 0):

yes easily you can do this for both **service A** and **service B** you will be having the deployment and service YAML file.

Ref file :

https://github.com/harsh4870/basic-ci-cd-cloudbuild/blob/main/deployment.yaml

You need to make sure both services should be deployed in same Kubernetes namespace or in other namespaces also it will work but need to set Host accordingly.

In kubernetes when service is deployed it can communicate to each other over the host name no need to specify the IP.

So inside kubernetes you have service with name A and want to talk with service B from service A you can hit directly http://..svc.cluster.local

```
http://b.namespace-name.svc.cluster.local
```

If you refer to official WordPress deployment also it uses the service name as the **Host** name. [Ref](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/mysql-wordpress-persistent-volume/)

```
- name: WORDPRESS_DB_HOST
  value: wordpress-mysql
```

So you can keep anything as a service name your use same name as Host name it will be able to communicate to each other.

[Spring boot ref](https://learnk8s.io/spring-boot-kubernetes-guide)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out.
Just like any other spring boot app I configured downstream services (service B) in application.yml file of service A and created image and deployed it in Kubernetes

Was able to get response back from service B into service A, when invkoked service A.

Thanks